# How can I use C-<left> C-<right> for backward/forard-word under MacOsX?

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I tried the following to assign Ctrl-left/right for moving one word forward/backward, but none of them works:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-left>") 'backward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-right>") 'forward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<left>") 'backward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<right>") 'forward-word)
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: What does ` C-h k` follow by hitting control and the right arrow report? That will show the key to use in `kbd`.

Comment: BTW, keyboard macros are something else. Your question concerns key bindings.

Comment: `C-h k` followed by C+<left> or C+<right> does not do anything (emacs does not take the key combination as input at all).

Comment: Then some other app or the OS "steal" it. Sorry, I don't have a Mac so have no clue how to change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl-left/right is assigned to Mission Control by default.  Remove the assignment of those two shortcuts in Mac OS X system preferences / keyboard / keyboard shortcuts: Chose Mission Control on the left side and uncheck assignments on the right side.