# Unset key in Prelude

Tags: key-bindings, prelude

I'm trying to remap `<C-right>` key action from `sp-forward-slurp-sexp`, which is set in Prelude by default, to `right-word`. I tried to put that code in my `init.el` in `.emacs.d/personal` folder:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-right>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-right>") 'right-word)
```

But this not work. Other code in `init.el` works well. Also i tried execute that code manually, via `C-x C-e`.

**Update**

Seems like i explained my problem wrong (sry for my bad English).

The problem is: after executing code above, behavior of key binding does not change, it still execute `sp-forward-slurp-sexp`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use C-<left> C-<right> for backward/forard-word under MacOsX?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/how-can-i-use-c-left-c-right-for-backward-forard-word-under-macosx)

Comment: 'sp-forward-slurp-sexp' comes from package smartparens, Check that with 'C-h k' and press C-right at the prompt. The output should tell the command and mode it is defined in. I doubt it is global mode and that might be the source of your problem. You'd need to redefine the key in that the same mode. See https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Working-with-expressions for a syntax example.  I can not easily test that because I use an other package, paredit, that does the same as smartparents.

Comment: Also, make sure your modifications load  *after* prelude and modules it uses have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This one is slightly convoluted, but you're looking for:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sp-override-key-bindings` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Add entries for, e.g., String: `<C-right>` with Symbol: `nil` to unbind that smartparens key sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in a Mac OS X, the OS assigns C-right to Mission Control and it never reaches emacs.

See [How can I use C-<left> C-<right> for backward/forard-word under MacOsX?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/how-can-i-use-c-left-c-right-for-backward-forard-word-under-macosx)

Comment: No, i'm on Linux. updated question.